# Thunderbolt Display Daisy Chain Mini Displayport Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport, dvi

I have an issue that I can't seem to be able to fix. Hope you can help me with that.

I have a MacBook Air 2012 13", a Thunderbolt display and a Samsung monitor connected through DVI on one end, and the other end DVI to Mini DisplayPort.

I would like this setup to occur: when connecting the MacBook Air to the Thunderbolt Display both the Thunderbolt Display and the Samsung display to work.

I have connected the Mini DisplayPort into the back of the Thunderbolt Display and connected the Thunderbolt display into my Mac, but the Samsung screen will not work.

Is there something I am doing that is wrong?

Comment: This is very unclear.  *How* are you connecting your monitors?  Thunderbolt or DisplayPort?  At one point you say it's working then you ask if it doesn't accept mini DisplayPort.  Can you please articulate what you have setup, how they are connected and  what your expected results are supposed to be.

Comment: I have updated the post to try to make the issue clearer. Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: According to the Technical Spec a 2012 13" Macbook Air cannot support multiple external displays. http://support.apple.com/kb/SP670   so I'm not sure if or how you are doing it now.  Your description of a DVI cable with two ends supporting a Thunderbolt Monitor and a Samsung one remains unclear.  Do you currently have two external monitors working somehow? Please describe the cabling.  As noted, daisy chaining won't work.  If you have a Macbook capable of supporting multiple external displays you need to use multiple Thunderbolt ports or a good docking station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have connected the Mini Displayport into the back of the Thunderbolt
>   Display and connected the Thunderbolt display into my Mac and the
>   Samsung screen will not work.

Unfortunately, this will not work.  You cannot attach (daisy chain) another monitor off of the Thunderbolt port on a Thunderbolt display. It's a limitation of the monitor, not the MBA

From AppleInsider:  [Apple clarifies Thunderbolt Display will not daisy chain Cinema Display](http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/09/16/apple_clarifies_thunderbolt_display_will_not_daisy_chain_cinema_display/)

> However, users with an existing Mini DisplayPort external monitor will
>   not be able to daisy chain the screen from the back of the new
>   Thunderbolt Display, despite it being physically compatible with the
>   port. Apple notes that "Mini DisplayPort displays will not light up if
>   connected to the Thunderbolt port on an Apple Thunderbolt Display."